# rdr is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm trying convert this VB.NET code into C#:

```vb
Protected Sub BT_KEM_CARIAN_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BT_KEM_CARIAN.Click
    Dim cmd As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("Select * from pengguna where idpengguna = @idpengguna", myconn)
    cmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.Text
    cmd.Connection = myconn

    Try
        myconn.Open()
        Dim rdr2 As SqlDataReader
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("idpengguna", KEMASKINI_MASUK.Text)
        rdr2 = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        rdr2.Read()
        KEMASKINI_ID.Text = rdr2("IDPENGGUNA").ToString
        KEMASKINI_IC.Text = rdr2("NoIC").ToString()
        KEMASKINI_NAMA.Text = rdr2("nama").ToString()
        KEMASKINI_MASUK.Text = rdr2("idpengguna").ToString()
        KEMASKINI_CAPAIAN.Text = rdr2("kodaccesslevel").ToString()
    Catch
        MsgBox("Succesfully Updated")
    End Try

    myconn.Close()
    MultiView1.SetActiveView(View4)
End Sub
```

Result:

```
protected void BT_KEM_CARIAN_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection myconn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DB"]);

    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("Select * from pengguna where idpengguna = @idpengguna", myconn);
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = myconn;

    try {
        myconn.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr2 = default(SqlDataReader);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("idpengguna", KEMASKINI_MASUK.Text);
        rdr2 = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        rdr2.Read();
        KEMASKINI_ID.Text = rdr2("IDPENGGUNA").ToString;
        KEMASKINI_IC.Text = rdr2("NoIC").ToString();
        KEMASKINI_NAMA.Text = rdr2("nama").ToString();
        KEMASKINI_MASUK.Text = rdr2("idpengguna").ToString();
        KEMASKINI_CAPAIAN.Text = rdr2("kodaccesslevel").ToString();
    } catch {
        Interaction.MsgBox("Succesfully Updated");
    }

    myconn.Close();
    MultiView1.SetActiveView(View4);
}
```

The below code gives the error

> rdr2 is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'

```
KEMASKINI_ID.Text = rdr2("IDPENGGUNA").ToString;
KEMASKINI_IC.Text = rdr2("NoIC").ToString();
KEMASKINI_NAMA.Text = rdr2("nama").ToString();
KEMASKINI_MASUK.Text = rdr2("idpengguna").ToString();
KEMASKINI_CAPAIAN.Text = rdr2("kodaccesslevel").ToString();
```

Comment: rdr2 is an object, not a method. Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C#, array items are referenced with square brackets, as opposed to VB where EVERYTHING is referenced with parentheses.  Change it to this:

```
KEMASKINI_ID.Text = rdr2["IDPENGGUNA"].ToString();
KEMASKINI_IC.Text = rdr2["NoIC"].ToString();
KEMASKINI_NAMA.Text = rdr2["nama"].ToString();
KEMASKINI_MASUK.Text = rdr2["idpengguna"].ToString();
KEMASKINI_CAPAIAN.Text = rdr2["kodaccesslevel"].ToString();
```

Comment: thanks Bill Gregg.. its cool.. but after i applied, i got this error on this line only.. KEMASKINI_ID.Text = rdr2["IDPENGGUNA"].ToString();     cannot convert method group 'toString' to non-degegate type 'string'. did you intend to invoke the method.

Comment: thanks Bill Gregg.. its cool.. but after i applied, i got this error on this line only.. KEMASKINI_ID.Text = rdr2["IDPENGGUNA"].ToString(); cannot convert method group 'toString' to non-degegate type 'string'. did you intend to invoke the method

Comment: You forgot the `();` at the end of that line actually. Double check that and you should be good.

Comment: Yes, I fixed that in your code when I recreated it.  Should have mentioned that too I guess.

Answer (score 1):

In VB.NET, `()` is both method call and indexing, so change it to `[]` for C#.

```
KEMASKINI_ID.Text = rdr2["IDPENGGUNA"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

In VB.NET, parens `()` are used for the default property. In C#, square brackets `[]` are used. Change `rdr2(...)` to `rdr2[...]`.